# OKD 4 support for operators

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin, okd

Kubernetes is an open source project (or even a framework), while OpenShift is a product that comes in many variants. There’s an open source version of OpenShift which is called OKD.

Does OKD-4 provide full access to users to Operators for installing databases like mongoDB, HDFS, elasitcSearch, janusgraph . Or these operators are supported out of the box only in licensed Openshift Container platform and not in open source OKD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, every operator which is opensource can be used in OKD

But in OCP there are also some operators which coming with a redhat openshift subscription, they are not opensourced, but mostly you will find an upstream operator project on github

example:
OpenShift Virtualization Operator
2.6.5 provided by Red Hat

you can look for the upstream opensource project and use this on OKD, because this is redhats DNA:
Kubevirt Operator
https://github.com/kubevirt/kubevirt/releases/download/v0.43.0/kubevirt-operator.yaml

Basically, if you find an operator on github for the type of application you want to deploy, you can do this on OKD.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Like Openshift, you can run Kubernetes Operators in OKD. Virtually there is no difference between OKD and Openshift apart from SLAs. You can check this reddit thread for more info: https://www.reddit.com/r/openshift/comments/dyrnlj/okd_vs_openshift/

**Update:** As @SYN pointed out that there some stability difference between OKD and OCP. Please read the fist comment for more details.

**Update 2:** As @ElytschaSmit pointed out that some operators are not available in OKD. Please check his comment for more details.

You should still be able to install the operators using Helm instead of the Marketplace.

Comment: Things have changed a little, between OpenShift 3 and 4. OCP is now upstream, OKD is late, less tested. Fedora CoreOS is another difference. Though RedHat CoreOS isn't much more stable. Also: while the OLM is available in OKD, OCP includes additional OperatorGroups: OKD collection is smaller, its operators are less likely to be supported. Having a simple OKD4.7 (no apps), operators / core services are crashing regularily, API often fails, comes down and back up, ... If you can afford support: try OCP. If you can't, better go with Kubernetes.

Comment: Thank your for the information @SYN . I wasn't aware of latest development in this section.

Comment: our Redhat CoreOS is rockstable until now, my okd cluster on fedora coreos also never crashed, a pain point with okd and generally openshift 4 are broken cluster upgrades, after you started a cluster upgrade to a version which breaks something, the only way to revert is to reinit your etcd with a backup before the upgrade..

Comment: There are some operators in OCP which are coming from the redhat marketplace, they are not available in OKD, but its mostly possible to find the upstream operator project for those redhat operators, so your statement is not totally correct.

Comment: Thank you @ElytschaSmith for pointing out that. I have added an update acknowledging your comment.